# Getting Data from more than two tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, join

here is my code of model

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('vf_training_district', 'vf_training_firm', 'complain_form');
$this->db->where('complain_form.InstituteId', 'vf_training_firm.FirmId');
$this->db->where('complain_form.DistrictId', 'vf_training_district.DistrictId');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result_array();
```

getting error of unknown column complain_form.InstituteId. each and every column is same as in db

Comment: You forgot to use [join](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

Comment: If any answer has helped you don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this helps you :**

```
 $this->db->select(*);
 $this->db->from('complain_form cf');
 $this->db->join('vf_training_firm vftf', 'vftf.FirmId = cf.InstituteId');
 $this->db->join('vf_training_district vftd', 'vftd.DistrictId = cf.DistrictId');

 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $result = $query->result_array();
```

**for more :** https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Answer (score 0):

You need [JOIN](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html):

```
SELECT *
  FROM complain_form 
  JOIN vf_training_firm ON complain_form.InstituteId = vf_training_firm.FirmId 
  JOIN vf_training_district ON complain_form.InstituteId = vf_training_district.DistrictId
```

using Query Builder class Codeigniter:

```
$row = $this->db->select(*)
                ->from('complain_form')
                ->join('vf_training_firm', 'complain_form.InstituteId = vf_training_firm.FirmId')
                ->join('vf_training_district', complain_form.InstituteId = vf_training_district.DistrictId)
                ->get();

return $row->result_array();
```